# XMLHttpRequest receiving 2 responses with onReadyStateChange

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

## What does it currently looks like?

I have a profile page which does a `POST` request when it's loaded to the server to receive the profile data from a user. It puts that data in inputs, so the user can modify those. Then at the bottom I have a button that sends the data from that form back to the server to update the data from the user. Now I want to send some sort of confirmation back to the client to notify the user that the data is updated successfully. So this is what it looks like currently.

```
On page load:
client -> server (post the userid)
server -> client (send the user data corresponding to the userid)
On button press:
client -> server (post the new user data)
server -> client (confirmation of the update)
```

## What do I use?

I am using javascript client sided. Server sided I am using Node.js with express.

## The problem and code

The things that happen on page load works perfectly fine. The last server to client response sends a json with `{Type: 1}` and it prints that literally on the browser which is not what I want, I think this is because the `XMLHttpRequest` isn't firing a second time. I want to catch this so I can make an appropriate response for this.

```
var xhp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        if (data.type == 0) {
            console.log(data);
            createProfileDiv(data);
        } else if (data.type == 1) {
            alert("Successfully edited your profile");
        }
    }
};
xhp.open("POST", "getProfile", true);
xhp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
xhp.send("id=" + getCookie("userId"));
```

This is the code for the profile page. I am trying with this code to make a difference between the data.type, so 0 is the receiving of the profile data and 1 is the receiving of the successfull message.

```
exports.getProfile = function(req, res) {
    let db = new sqlite3.Database('database', sqlite3.OPEN_READ, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        }
    });

    var profile = {};
    db.get(`SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE customer_id = (?);`, [req.body.id], (err, row) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        }
        profile = row;
    });

    db.close((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        } else {
            profile.type = 0;
            res.send(profile);
        }
    });
}

exports.updateProfile = function(data, res) {
    let db = new sqlite3.Database('database', sqlite3.OPEN_READ, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        }
    });
    db.get('UPDATE Customers SET name=(?), password=(?), email=(?), address=(?), city=(?), zip_code=(?), birthdate=(?) WHERE email=(?);',
    [data.body.name, data.body.password, data.body.email, data.body.address, data.body.city, data.body.zipcode, data.body.birthdate, data.body.email],
    (err, row) => {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err.message);
        }
    });
    db.close((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        } else {
            var obj = {type: 1};
        res.status(200);
        res.send(obj);
        }
    });
}
```

The first fuction `getProfile` gets the data from the database and then sends that together with type 0 to the client, The second function 'updateProfile' updates the data from the database and then sends the type 1 message to the client as confirmation that the update has been successful. The thing I literally get client sided is a white page saying: "{type:1}", but the onreadystatechange isn't getting called?

## Question

So my question is. Am I doing something completely stupid, if so, how should I do it? Else why isn't my onreadystatechange not getting called a second time for the updateprofile request?

Comment: Sounds like you are calling second request from a form control event and not preventing default form submit and page loads the ajax endpoint when form submits. Is that description accurate?

Comment: Yes that is accurate. In the form however I didn’t specify an action, so that means the endpoint is the url the form is on, am I right? Should I prevent the default submit in JavaScript and send the data from there?

Comment: Yes to both.... Once prevented should work as you expect

Comment: Thank you, I’ll post an update tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for Charlietfl for this answer.
The way I did it was by preventing the default form submit and make the request send using a xmlhttprequest.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        if (data.type == 0) {
            createProfileDiv(data);
            changeSubmitFunction();
        } else if (data.type == 1) {
            console.log("jaaaa1");

        }
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("POST", "getProfile", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.send("id=" + getCookie("userId"));

function changeSubmitFunction() {
    var form = document.getElementById("profile-form");
    form.onsubmit = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "updateProfile", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/JSON");
        var formData = new FormData(form);
        let reqBody = {};
        for (let entry of formData.entries()) {
            reqBody[entry[0]] = entry[1];
        }
        xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(reqBody));
        return false;
    }
}
```